# can't free memory correctly

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on pset6 of Harvard's cs50 now, the problem is to implement a trie dictionary.
I finally managed to make it work with a small problem.

1. When I run valgrind to check memory leak, it tells me that I've freed one more than I've allocated, but I can't see any problem in my unload function.
2. It also warns me that there are some uninitialized values, but I can't figure it out although it won't affect the result.

Here is my entire code:

```
/****************************************************************************
 * dictionary.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 6
 *
 * valgrind warn that there are uninitialized values, could be the node struct, but don't
 * know how to initialize it, anyway, it works at last!
 * 
 * Implements a dictionary's functionality.
 ***************************************************************************/

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>   
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HASHTABLE_SIZE 5000

int count = 0;     // gloabal counter

typedef struct node {         // data structure 
    bool end_word;
    struct node *children[27];
    } node;

int
charNumber(char c);   // function prototype

void 
freeNode(node *currentNode);

node root = {false,{NULL}};
/*
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */

bool
check(const char *word)
{
    node *ptr = &root;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++)
    {
        if (ptr->children[charNumber(word[i])] == NULL)
            return false;
        ptr = ptr->children[charNumber(word[i])];
    }
    if (ptr->end_word)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


/*
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{
//    char word[LENGTH+1];  // must initialize to zero! Or there will be some weird problem.
    FILE *fp = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return false;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        char word[LENGTH+1] = {};
        fscanf(fp,"%s\n",word); // have to use "%s\n" instead of "%s", or the count will be wrong, don't know why.
        count++;    
        node *ptr = &root;
        for (int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++)
        {
            if (ptr->children[charNumber(word[i])] == NULL)
            {
                node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));   
                *new = (node) {false,{NULL}};       // initiallization
                ptr->children[charNumber(word[i])] = new;
                ptr = new;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr = ptr->children[charNumber(word[i])];
            }
         }
         ptr->end_word = true;
    }
fclose(fp);           
return true;
}


/*
 * caculate a number for the character
 */

int
charNumber(char c)
{
    int num;
    if (c == '\'')
        return 26;
    else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        c += 32;
    num = c - 'a';
    return num;
}



/*
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */

unsigned int
size(void)
{
    if (count)
        return count;
    else
        return 0;
}


/*
 * Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

bool
unload(void)
{
    freeNode(&root);
    return true;         // can't figure out when to return false...
}

void freeNode(node *currentNode)
{
    for (int i=0;i<27;i++)
    {
        if (currentNode->children[i] != NULL)
            freeNode(currentNode->children[i]);
    }
    free(currentNode);
 }
```

Here is some of the valgrind output:

```
==22110== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==22110==    at 0x4024ECD: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==22110==    by 0x8048F90: freeNode (dictionary_tries.c:152)
==22110==    by 0x8048F45: unload (dictionary_tries.c:141)
==22110==    by 0x8048AB5: main (speller.c:158)
==22110==  Address 0x804a5a0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "root"
==22110==
--22110-- REDIR: 0x40b2930 (strchrnul) redirected to 0x4028570 (strchrnul)


==22110==
==22110== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22110==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22110==   total heap usage: 367,083 allocs, 367,084 frees, 41,113,776 bytes allocated
==22110==
==22110== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22110==
==22110== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 14 from 9)
==22110==
==22110== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==22110== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==22110==    at 0x4024ECD: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==22110==    by 0x8048F90: freeNode (dictionary_tries.c:152)
==22110==    by 0x8048F45: unload (dictionary_tries.c:141)
==22110==    by 0x8048AB5: main (speller.c:158)
==22110==  Address 0x804a5a0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "root"
==22110==
--22110--
--22110-- used_suppression:     14 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
==22110==
==22110== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 14 from 9)
```

Comment: don't use `new` as variable name.

Comment: Please don't tag C code with C++; the memory management techniques that are native to the languages are quite different.  And in C++, `new` is a keyword, so your code is strictly, but strictly, C code and nothing to do with C++.

Comment: If `valgrind` is giving you warnings, then you should include representative examples of those warnings in the question.  If `valgrind` is not giving you precise line numbers, you need to compile the code with debugging enabled (usually `-g`) so that it can tell you which line numbers are going wrong. Note that `malloc()` does not initialize the memory; you don't seem to initialize the `children` part of the structure when you first allocate it, which would lead to problems.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:sorry about the c++ tag if it causes any confusion to you, just a noob here..

Comment: I'm not confused; I'm just letting you know that it makes you seem confused.  C and C++ are two very different languages.  Dual tagging is seldom correct — though it happens quite often.  Don't fret too much (but don't do it again) — we were all new here once upon a time.  Since you don't include a `main()` program, your code is not complete, despite your assertion to the contrary.

Comment: In fact, the C tag wiki makes it fairly clear that you *shouldn't* tag C and C++ together. Aside from that, I hope you're not attempting to `freeNode(&root);`...

Comment: Can you try check if pointer is null before free or delete?

Comment: You are trying to free `root` which you didn't allocate.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your `load` function opens a blank file. `feof(fp)` will initially return `0`, because a read operation hasn't been used yet; The `EOF` flag will only be set after a read operation returns a value indicating an error. This is where an error lies. In your case, you need to loop on the return value of `fscanf(fp,"%s\n",word);` rather than the return value of `feof`. For example:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) == 1) {
    /* ... */
}

if (feof(fp)) {
    /* The loop ended due to EOF */
}
else if (ferror(fp)) {
    /* The loop ended due to some file input error */
}
else {
    /* The loop ended because the input was invalid
     * (this applies to input where a conversion is
     *  required eg. the conversion in %d, %u, %f, etc... */
}
```

To elaborate, `feof` is *only for determining why the last read failed*!

The reason this would cause such a warning in the case of a blank file is that `word` would contain indeterminate information.

Additionally, `freeNode(&root);` is erroneous because `free` is only to be called on pointers that are returned by `calloc`, `realloc` and `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
node root = {false,{NULL}};
```

is not allocated on the heap, but then you try to free it like it is

```
unload(void)
{
    freeNode(&root);
```

Comment: Actually, `root` is a global variable and is therefore not likely to be allocated on the stack.  You're right that it is not dynamically allocated and therefore should not be freed, though.

Comment: Where-ever the implementation decides to put it. Remember, the stack and the heap are in the same place...

Comment: @xaxxon - Line 42 (Aint it funny how many questions than number answers!)

Comment: @enhzflep not sure if you're being serious or trying to be funny, but I meant where is the memory for the variable allocated.

Comment: @xaxxon yes,that's exactly what i went wrong, but how can fix it? I've tried to malloc a memory for root also, but no luck,it seems that you can only initilize a compile-time constant expression globally in c99.

Comment: @xaxxon Actually, I was being serious. Though it does seem amusing in retrospect. (it *is* line 42 for what it's worth) From my rusty memory banks, the memory that the root variable inhabits would be the stack if it were in a function, but as it stands, my answer would be 'in the program's data segment'. Though I was much better 30 years ago (as I am still) with examples of use, rather than the proper names for them. To this day, it still takes me a moment to articulate what a noun,verb and adjective each are.

Comment: @linuxfish just don't clean it up.  You don't need to.  If you need a number of them that you can't determine at compile-time, then you will need to malloc it and you can free it.  node * node = malloc(sizeof(node)); then initialize it.